# deploy app with dll wrapper

Tags: winforms, dll, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a WinForms application that involves importing an external DLL with a wrapper class, like this:

```
[DllImport(ImportedDllName, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void cfg_put_MixerFilePlayerEnabled(IntPtr cfgPtr, int Enabled);

[DllImport(ImportedDllName, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
private static extern void cfg_get_MixerFilePlayerEnabled(IntPtr cfgPtr, ref int Enabled);

public int MixerFilePlayerEnabled
{
    get { int s = 0; cfg_get_MixerFilePlayerEnabled(m_cfgPtr, ref s); return s; }
    set { cfg_put_MixerFilePlayerEnabled(m_cfgPtr, value); }
}
```

So, when I run my application debbugin, all work right, but when I publish it, I receive a `DLL not found` exception.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your debug machine and publish machine are the same PC:

1. Find out "the external DLL" is x86 or x64. Your C# wrapper should also run as x86 or x64 correspondingly.
2. Use [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)  to make sure you C# wrapper can find the "the external DLL".
3. Write a cpp exe demo to make sure cpp exe can use that dll. Then try C# wrapper.

If your debug machine and publish machine are two PCs:

1. Install the right version of vcredist of "the external DLL".
2. Use [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what dll you missed.
3. Write a cpp exe demo to make sure cpp exe can use that dll. Then try C# wrapper.